# Как сохранить отпечаток пальца в БД?

Tags: flutter, dart

хочу написать приложение, которое предоставляет информацию о человеке на основе его биометрии пальца.

Например приложил человек палец, данные отправились на сервер, сервер выдал, что это такой то человек и выдал о нем информацию.

Я сейчас пишу на языке Dart+Flutter и хочу получить биометрию, когда человек приложит палец, в итоге я так понимаю я должен получить какую то длинную строку или набор json, объясните пожалуйста что я должен получить в итоге и как это получить? Было бы хорошо понять, как потом это распознать на сервере, там в принципе я думаю уже можно использовать Python с огромным набором библиотек для этого дела.

В основном мне сейчас нужно что то получить преобразовать и отправить

Comment: Никаких данных вы не можете получить. Иначе это будет небезопасно. Апи биометрии вас только уведомляет, что пользователь успешно авторизовался(или неуспешно).